# JTable storing row values as object

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, jtable

At the moment, i have a table that has no row values when it is built, rows are added in after i click the `add` button. when i click the `add` button, it will add a row to the table and there are `cells` for the user to key in values. And then when i click the `save` button it will store each of the col value into an object. I just wanted to know if there is a more efficient way to do it instead of my `if else`.

```
package UI;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TableManage extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4353951253754938210L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTable tablemanage;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TableManage frame = new TableManage();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TableManage() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    DefaultTableModel manageModel;  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {

            },
            new String[] {
                "NAME", "AGE", "GENDER"
            }


            );
    tablemanage = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane managementpane=new JScrollPane(tablemanage);

    managementpane.setBounds(40, 11, 355, 118);
    contentPane.add(managementpane);

    JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
    btnAdd.setBounds(40, 164, 89, 23);
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.addRow(new Object [][] {{null, null,null}});
            model.setValueAt(null,tablemanage.getRowCount()-1,0);

        }
    });

    contentPane.add(btnAdd);

    JButton btnRemove = new JButton("REMOVE");
    btnRemove.setBounds(172, 164, 89, 23);
    btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(tablemanage.getSelectedRow()<0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Select value To Remove");

            }
            else
            {
                model.removeRow(tablemanage.getSelectedRow());
            }

        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnRemove);

    JButton btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
    btnSave.setBounds(306, 164, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnSave);

    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int nu=tablemanage.getRowCount();
            int co=tablemanage.getColumnCount();
            tablemanage.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            int i;
            int j;
            ArrayList<TestingObject> testList=new ArrayList<TestingObject>();
            TestingObject test=new TestingObject();
            for( i=0;i<nu;i++)
            {
                test=new TestingObject();
                for( j=0;j<co;j++)
                {

                    System.out.println(j);

                    if(j==0){
                        test.setName((String) tablemanage.getModel().getValueAt(i,j));
                    }
                    else if(j==1){
                        test.setAge((String) tablemanage.getModel().getValueAt(i,j));
                    }
                    else{
                        test.setGender((String) tablemanage.getModel().getValueAt(i,j));
                    }

                }
                testList.add(test);
                System.out.println ();
            }

            for(int k=0;k<testList.size();k++){
                testList.get(k).print();
            }

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Don't use a null layout and the setBounds(...) method. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove inner `for-loop` inside `btnSave action lister` and put this codes
because your `column count` is always `3`

```
    test=new TestingObject();

    test.setName((String) tablemanage.getModel().getValueAt(i,0));
    test.setAge((String) tablemanage.getModel().getValueAt(i,1));
    test.setGender((String) tablemanage.getModel().getValueAt(i,2));

    testList.add(test);
```

and use this standard code **it can be used with jdk 1.8** to print array list values

```
testList.stream().forEach((var) -> {
     System.out.println(var);
});
```